# VBA Code That Extracts From Multiple Sheets to New Multiple Sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I am somewhat of a novice VBA user and I have created a workbook that has a Userform with several tabs.  When the user selects the appropriate tab and inputs data it gets transferred to the applicable worksheet.  I have a command button on a worksheet that when clicked it prompts for a date range and then I want it to extract the transferred data from each applicable worksheet and place it onto separate new worksheets for each user (because everyone's data is different). The below VBA code I have compiled is not processing correctly.  Instead it only pulls data from one worksheet and puts it on all of the new individual worksheets.

```
Sub Copy_Click()

Dim startdate As Date, enddate As Date
Dim rng As Range, destRow As Long
Dim shtSrc1 As Worksheet
Dim shtSrc2 As Worksheet
Dim shtSrc3 As Worksheet
Dim shtDest1 As Worksheet
Dim shtDest2 As Worksheet
Dim shtDest3 As Worksheet

Dim c As Range

Set shtSrc1 = Sheets("Recruiter")
Set shtSrc2 = Sheets("SrRecruiter")
Set shtSrc3 = Sheets("RecruiterSpc")

Set shtDest1 = Sheets("Extract_Recrt")
Set shtDest2 = Sheets("Extract_SrRecrt")
Set shtDest3 = Sheets("Extract_RecrtSpc")

destRow = 2 'start copying to this row

startdate = CDate(InputBox("Input desired start date for report data"))
enddate = CDate(InputBox("Input desired end date for report data"))

'don't scan the entire column...
Set rng = Application.Intersect(shtSrc1.Range("A:A"), shtSrc1.UsedRange)
Set rng = Application.Intersect(shtSrc2.Range("A:A"), shtSrc2.UsedRange)
Set rng = Application.Intersect(shtSrc3.Range("A:A"), shtSrc3.UsedRange)

For Each c In rng.Cells
    If c.Value >= startdate And c.Value <= enddate Then

        c.Offset(0, 0).Resize(1, 25).Copy _
                      shtDest1.Cells(destRow, 1)

        c.Offset(0, 0).Resize(1, 25).Copy _
                      shtDest2.Cells(destRow, 1)

        c.Offset(0, 0).Resize(1, 25).Copy _
                      shtDest3.Cells(destRow, 1)


        destRow = destRow + 1

         End If
     Next

  End Sub
```

Can anyone please show me what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not so sure about your needs but you can try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub Copy_Click()
Dim startdate As Date, enddate As Date
Dim rng As Range, c As Range
Dim destRow(1 To 3) As Long
Dim shtSrc(1 To 3) As Worksheet
Dim shtDest(1 To 3) As Worksheet
Dim i As Long    

Set shtSrc(1) = Sheets("Recruiter")
Set shtSrc(2) = Sheets("SrRecruiter")
Set shtSrc(3) = Sheets("RecruiterSpc")

Set shtDest(1) = Sheets("Extract_Recrt")
Set shtDest(2) = Sheets("Extract_SrRecrt")
Set shtDest(3) = Sheets("Extract_RecrtSpc")

destRow(1) = 2: destRow(2) = 2: destRow(3) = 2

startdate = CDate(InputBox("Input desired start date for report data"))
enddate = CDate(InputBox("Input desired end date for report data"))

For i = 1 To 3
    Set rng = shtSrc(i).Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers) 'this will select only numbers constants. since dates are numbers they'll get into this range
    For Each c In rng
        If c.Value >= startdate And c.Value <= enddate Then
             c.Offset(0, 0).Resize(1, 25).Copy Destination:=shtDest(i).Cells(destRow(i), 1)
             destRow(i) = destRow(i) + 1
        End If
    Next c
Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: YES!!!! Thank you soooo very much.  This is exactly what I needed/wanted and it works perfectly.  It even overwrites the existing data with the new data.  Many thanks to all users of this forum who take time out of their busy schedules to help others, it is so greatly appreciated!  :)

Comment: Glad it helped. If I fullfilled your question, please mark my answer as the solution. Thank you

Comment: I am unsure of how to mark your answer as the solution....do I need to do something special to the post?

Comment: User3598756--I have one additional issue I'd like to ask if you could help me solve.  I'd like to use the same kind of theory to pull monthly data.  I may not be able to post all of my issue in this comment but I'll try.  I want to have a command button that when clicked prompts the user to enter a begin/end date to pull data from specific columns from multiple sheets and transfer the results to a master tab.  I think I'm overcomplicating how to go about this.  Can you please provide direction.

Comment: So using the same code you modified for me earlier, I want to pull from each of the six sheets based on a begin/end date but I want to extract from specific columns only and transfer the results to one sheet destination.  Thank you.

Comment: to accept an answer you must "click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in" (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). as for the new request you have to start a new question...

Answer (score 1):

Firstly it looks like you are setting the `rng` variable and then overwriting it.
I would change the code to something like this to accommodate the 3 `rng` variables that seem to be needed.

ie,

```
Dim rng(1 To 3)

Set rng(1) = Application.Intersect(shtSrc1.Range("A:A"), shtSrc1.UsedRange)
Set rng(2) = Application.Intersect(shtSrc2.Range("A:A"), shtSrc2.UsedRange)
Set rng(3) = Application.Intersect(shtSrc3.Range("A:A"), shtSrc3.UsedRange)
```

Then use a `for loop` to loop through each range you just set. The complete code is below for reference.

```
Sub Copy_Click()
  　Dim startdate As Date, enddate As Date
    Dim rng(1 To 3) As Range, destRow As Long
    Dim shtSrc1 As Worksheet
    Dim shtSrc2 As Worksheet
    Dim shtSrc3 As Worksheet
    Dim shtDest(1 To 3) As Worksheet


    Dim c As Range

    Set shtSrc1 = Sheets("Recruiter")
    Set shtSrc2 = Sheets("SrRecruiter")
    Set shtSrc3 = Sheets("RecruiterSpc")

    Set shtDest(1) = Sheets("Extract_Recrt")
    Set shtDest(2) = Sheets("Extract_SrRecrt")
    Set shtDest(3) = Sheets("Extract_RecrtSpc")

    destRow = 2 'start copying to this row

    startdate = CDate(InputBox("Input desired start date for report data"))
    enddate = CDate(InputBox("Input desired end date for report data"))
       If IsDate(stardate) = False Then Exit Sub
    'don't scan the entire column...
    Set rng(1) = Application.Intersect(shtSrc1.Range("A:A"), shtSrc1.UsedRange)
    Set rng(2) = Application.Intersect(shtSrc2.Range("A:A"), shtSrc2.UsedRange)
    Set rng(3) = Application.Intersect(shtSrc3.Range("A:A"), shtSrc3.UsedRange)

           For i = LBound(rng) To UBound(rng)
               For Each c In rng(i).Cells
                  If c.Value >= startdate And c.Value <= enddate Then

                        c.Offset(0, 0).Resize(1, 25).Copy _
                                      shtDest(i).Cells(destRow, 1)
                        destRow = destRow + 1

                     End If
                 Next
            Next i
      End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining about separate ranges.  Unfortunately, the code provided is combining all the information and repeating/placing it onto each of the new individual sheets.  Instead once a date range is input for all sheets, I need the data to pull from each applicable sheet for the given date and transfer on a new sheet for each applicable role type (i.e., Recruiter data pulled and place on new sheet, Sr. Recruiter data pulled and placed on new sheet.  Please help...thank you